# Pandas - Groupby with no aggregation

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to perform a group by of data wherein I am trying to show the actual values in a group by function and perform no aggregation.

```
ticket_id,date,status
101,2020-01-01,Done
101,2020-01-02,Done
101,2020-01-03,Open
101,2020-01-04,Cancelled
101,2020-01-05,Pending
102,2020-01-01,Done
102,2020-01-03,Open
103,2020-01-04,Done
103,2020-01-06,Cancelled
```

Expected the below output such that there is no aggregation but the actual values are shown as it is.

```
    2020-01-01,2020-01-02,2020-01-03,2020-01-04,2020-01-05,2020-01-06
101 Done,Done,Open,Cancelled,Pending,
102 Done,,Open
103 ,,,Done,,Cancelled
```

Comment: try pivot : `df.pivot(*df)` works

Comment: @anky_91, thanks figured out the expected output..